# Using @DataJpaTest when multiple datasources are configured

Tags: spring, spring-data-jpa, spring-test

My application is configured with two datasources, following this example: https://github.com/snicoll-demos/demo-multi-entity-managers

Everything works when running the app, but when I try to add a @DataJpaTest, it isn't able to load the application context:

```
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'entityManagerFactory' defined in class path resource [com/example/reports/ws/MainDatabaseConfig.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean]: Factory method 'mainEntityManager' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: No visible constructors in class org.springframework.boot.test.autoconfigure.jdbc.TestDatabaseAutoConfiguration$EmbeddedDataSourceFactoryBean
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:599)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1173)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1067)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:513)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:483)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:306)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:302)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:197)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.getBean(AbstractApplicationContext.java:1080)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:857)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:543)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:693)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:360)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:303)
    at org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootContextLoader.loadContext(SpringBootContextLoader.java:120)
    at org.springframework.test.context.cache.DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.loadContextInternal(DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.java:98)
    at org.springframework.test.context.cache.DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.loadContext(DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.java:116)
    ... 49 more
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean]: Factory method 'mainEntityManager' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: No visible constructors in class org.springframework.boot.test.autoconfigure.jdbc.TestDatabaseAutoConfiguration$EmbeddedDataSourceFactoryBean
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:189)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:588)
    ... 66 more
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: No visible constructors in class org.springframework.boot.test.autoconfigure.jdbc.TestDatabaseAutoConfiguration$EmbeddedDataSourceFactoryBean
    at org.springframework.cglib.proxy.Enhancer.filterConstructors(Enhancer.java:666)
    at org.springframework.cglib.proxy.Enhancer.generateClass(Enhancer.java:567)
    at org.springframework.cglib.core.DefaultGeneratorStrategy.generate(DefaultGeneratorStrategy.java:25)
    at org.springframework.cglib.core.AbstractClassGenerator.generate(AbstractClassGenerator.java:329)
    at org.springframework.cglib.proxy.Enhancer.generate(Enhancer.java:492)
    at org.springframework.cglib.core.AbstractClassGenerator$ClassLoaderData$3.apply(AbstractClassGenerator.java:93)
    at org.springframework.cglib.core.AbstractClassGenerator$ClassLoaderData$3.apply(AbstractClassGenerator.java:91)
    at org.springframework.cglib.core.internal.LoadingCache$2.call(LoadingCache.java:54)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at org.springframework.cglib.core.internal.LoadingCache.createEntry(LoadingCache.java:61)
    at org.springframework.cglib.core.internal.LoadingCache.get(LoadingCache.java:34)
    at org.springframework.cglib.core.AbstractClassGenerator$ClassLoaderData.get(AbstractClassGenerator.java:116)
    at org.springframework.cglib.core.AbstractClassGenerator.create(AbstractClassGenerator.java:291)
    at org.springframework.cglib.proxy.Enhancer.createHelper(Enhancer.java:480)
    at org.springframework.cglib.proxy.Enhancer.createClass(Enhancer.java:337)
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassEnhancer$BeanMethodInterceptor.createCglibProxyForFactoryBean(ConfigurationClassEnhancer.java:531)
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassEnhancer$BeanMethodInterceptor.enhanceFactoryBean(ConfigurationClassEnhancer.java:502)
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassEnhancer$BeanMethodInterceptor.intercept(ConfigurationClassEnhancer.java:340)
    at com.example.reports.ws.MainDatabaseConfig$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$22c681c6.mainDataSource(<generated>)
    at com.example.reports.ws.MainDatabaseConfig.mainEntityManager(MainDatabaseConfig.java:59)
    at com.example.reports.ws.MainDatabaseConfig$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$22c681c6.CGLIB$mainEntityManager$2(<generated>)
    at com.example.reports.ws.MainDatabaseConfig$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$22c681c6$$FastClassBySpringCGLIB$$c8213502.invoke(<generated>)
    at org.springframework.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invokeSuper(MethodProxy.java:228)
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassEnhancer$BeanMethodInterceptor.intercept(ConfigurationClassEnhancer.java:358)
    at com.example.reports.ws.MainDatabaseConfig$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$22c681c6.mainEntityManager(<generated>)
```

Anyone know what I need to do to get Spring's magic working in this setup?

---

The configuration for my main database:

```
package com.example.reports.ws;

import javax.persistence.EntityManagerFactory;

import org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.DataSource;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.domain.EntityScan;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.jdbc.DataSourceBuilder;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.orm.jpa.JpaProperties;
import org.springframework.boot.context.properties.ConfigurationProperties;
import org.springframework.boot.orm.jpa.EntityManagerFactoryBuilder;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Primary;
import org.springframework.core.env.Environment;
import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.config.EnableJpaRepositories;
import org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager;
import org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaVendorAdapter;
import org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean;
import org.springframework.orm.jpa.persistenceunit.PersistenceUnitManager;
import org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.AbstractJpaVendorAdapter;
import org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaVendorAdapter;
import org.springframework.transaction.PlatformTransactionManager;
import org.springframework.transaction.annotation.EnableTransactionManagement;

import com.example.reports.ws.model.ReportDefinition;
import com.example.reports.ws.repos.ChartPrefsRepository;
import com.example.reports.ws.svc.ChartService;

@Configuration
@EntityScan
@EnableTransactionManagement()
@EnableJpaRepositories(entityManagerFactoryRef = "entityManagerFactory", transactionManagerRef = "mainTransactionManager", basePackages = "com.example.reports.ws.repos")
public class MainDatabaseConfig {

    @Autowired
    private Environment env;

    @Autowired(required = false)
    private PersistenceUnitManager persistenceUnitManager;

    @Bean
    @ConfigurationProperties("app.main.jpa")
    public JpaProperties mainJpaProperties() {
        return new JpaProperties();
    }

    @Bean
    @Primary
    @ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "app.main.datasource")
    public DataSource mainDataSource() {
        return (DataSource) DataSourceBuilder.create().type(DataSource.class).build();
    }

    @Bean(name = "entityManagerFactory")
    @Primary
    public LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean mainEntityManager(JpaProperties mainJpaProperties) {
        EntityManagerFactoryBuilder builder = createEntityManagerFactoryBuilder(mainJpaProperties);
        return builder.dataSource(mainDataSource())
                .packages(ReportDefinition.class, ChartPrefsRepository.class, ChartService.class)
                .persistenceUnit("mainDs").build();
    }

    private EntityManagerFactoryBuilder createEntityManagerFactoryBuilder(JpaProperties mainJpaProperties) {
        JpaVendorAdapter jpaVendorAdapter = createJpaVendorAdapter(mainJpaProperties);
        return new EntityManagerFactoryBuilder(jpaVendorAdapter, mainJpaProperties.getProperties(),
                this.persistenceUnitManager);
    }

    private JpaVendorAdapter createJpaVendorAdapter(JpaProperties jpaProperties) {
        AbstractJpaVendorAdapter adapter = new HibernateJpaVendorAdapter();
        adapter.setShowSql(jpaProperties.isShowSql());
        adapter.setDatabase(jpaProperties.getDatabase());
        adapter.setDatabasePlatform(jpaProperties.getDatabasePlatform());
        adapter.setGenerateDdl(jpaProperties.isGenerateDdl());
        return adapter;
    }

    @Bean
    @Primary
    public PlatformTransactionManager mainTransactionManager(EntityManagerFactory mainEntityManager) {
        return new JpaTransactionManager(mainEntityManager);
    }

}
```

Comment: What version of Spring Boot are you using?

Comment: @SamBrannen 1.5.9

Comment: Can you please add the `@Bean` method named `mainEntityManager` to your question? And the rest of the containing `@Configuration` class if possible?

Comment: @SamBrannen added

Comment: It appears that _something_ is attempting to use CGLIB to dynamically subclass infrastructure beans. Are you by any chance using AOP (e.g., AspectJ pointcuts) to apply advice to beans in the `ApplicationContext`?

Comment: What happens if you switch to using a single `DataSource`, etc.? Do you still have the same problem with CGLIB?